# Laravel 5.3 get all records and then update it

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.3. In my notification model, I require to get all unread notification and then update it as read.

Correctly I have to do with foreach after `Model::where()->get();`

May be available with `map();` before `get();`

As my think it should possible with

```
$notifications->map( function($noti){
    $noti->is_read= 1;
    $noti->update();
});
```

But it's not working.

Comment: i wouldn't go with a foreach here. Every loop will result in a db query. You should update them all at once with a specific query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update all at once. With the same where clause as in your select

```
Model::where( ... )->update(['read' => true]);
```

Or whatever is your read indicator

Comment: Thanks for your replay,
Bt i required that records. Using this i need to get all record again.

Comment: As my think it should possible with

$notifications->map( function($noti){
            $noti->is_read= 1;
            $noti->update();
        });

But it's not working.

Comment: you are still running better with two requests. One for reading and one for updating. You shouldn't loop if you expect more than 3 notifications.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was bad idea to update in loop, it will causes more SQL load in back-end. Thank for your replay.